# Select fragment of a text in JTextArea

Tags: java, selection, jtextarea

I need to select some fragment of a text in JTextArea. How should i do that?...

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which fragment of the text? The first word, a specific expression, ...?

Comment: Do you mean from another program then the one which contains the JTextArea ? I don't get the `manually` though...

Comment: i mean, for example, to select last word. from space to space, i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setCaretPosition(selectionStart)` followed by `moveCaretPosition(selectionEnd)`. This is documented in [JTextComponent's javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html)